# How to navigate to parent route from child route (angular)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've been looking around but still haven't found an answer that works for my particular example.

```
  { path: "", component: NavbarComponent },
  {
    path: "signup",
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: SignupComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want to navigate back to the navbar component from the signupcomponent. Some other answers on SO say to do something like: this.router.navigate(["./"], { relativeTo: this.route }); but this does not work. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: I believe that "../" checks sibling routes, while "../../" navigates up to a parent route.

Comment: I dont think you need relativeTo and then just have "/" as the location. so like `this.router.navigate(['/']);` to get to your NavbarComponent,

Comment: I figured it out. You do need to use relativeTo, then it is just like navigating folders, so just "../" works

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a button and the href attribute like that:

```
<ion-button slot = "start" href="/home">
```